# Problem with method AudioRecord.read - Return value -1 (Android)

Tags: android, audiorecord

I have a problem with the Android AudioRecord library.
I need to record an audio stream from the device's microphone.

The initialization of the class is as follows:

```
    recorder = new AudioRecord(
            currentAudioSource,
            SAMPLE_RATE_IN_8KHZ,
            CHANNEL, // Mono
            ENCODING, // ENCODING_PCM_16BIT
            bufferSize // 2048
    );
```

Then, I call *recorder.startRecording()* to make the audio stream active.

And to acquire this flow I call the method in a loop:

```
recorder.read(samples, 0, currentBufferSize)
```

The variable *samples* is a short[] and *currentBufferSize* is the lenght of the buffer.
The "read" method works correctly for the first N loop.

At loop N + 1, the method is stuck waiting to give me back 2048 short, until I call the *stopRecording* which gives me the registered values (less than 2048 short).

On the next registration, the read method returns me an empty short [] and the error code "-1" (general error).

It's been a few days since I got it right, also because the error does not occur in a systematic way, but randomly on multiple devices.

Do you have any ideas to resolve this situation?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I solved with this solution:

```
while(runWorker) {
   if (recorder != null && recorder.getRecordingState() == AudioRecord.RECORDSTATE_RECORDING) {
   ...
   Thread.sleep(40);
   sampled = this.recorder.read(samples, 0, currentBufferSize, AudioRecord.READ_NON_BLOCKING);
   ...
```

I inserted a 40 ms pause and used the non-blocking Read.
This works on all devices except some Samsung tablets. This is the related post: [AudioRecord.read with read mode: READ_NON_BLOCKING not working on Tablet Samsung](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73049564/audiorecord-read-with-read-mode-read-non-blocking-not-working-on-tablet-samsung)

On Samsung tablets, the non-blocking Read always returns the value 0, as if it were not recording audio. If I use AudioRecord.READ_BLOCKING it works correctly.

Do you have any ideas about it?
Thanks.

Michele